Unable to access mapped memory
Why can not access the memory after 0x010ff8
(gdb) br *0x0100e2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100e2
(gdb) run
...
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000000100e2 in ?? ()
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 2563326
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
             0x10000            0x20000    0x10000        0x0  rwxp   /home/glaudiston/src/gelf/tests/test_s2i.elf
      0x7ffff7ff9000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x4000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0  --xp   [vsyscall]
(gdb) x/32xb 0x10ff0
0x10ff0:    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x10ff8:    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x11000:    Cannot access memory at address 0x11000

here is the elf:
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 7800 0100 0000 0000  ..>.....x.......
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  @...............
00000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0100 0000 0000 0000  ....@.8.........
00000040: 0100 0000 0700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 eb31 4889 e048 83c0  .........1H..H..
00000080: 1848 8b00 488b 0048 8b00 4831 c948 31f6  .H..H..H..H1.H1.
00000090: 4088 c63c 0074 1083 ee30 486b c90a 4801  @..<.t...0Hk..H.
000000a0: f148 c1e8 08eb e948 89cf c348 89e6 4883  .H.....H...H..H.
000000b0: c610 4c01 fe48 89f1 4883 c108 488b 0948  ..L..H..H...H..H
000000c0: 83f9 0074 0548 29ce eb18 5648 8b36 4889  ...t.H)...VH.6H.
000000d0: f148 8b01 48ff c184 c075 f648 ffc9 4829  .H..H....u.H..H)
000000e0: f15e 488b 3648 c7c7 f90f 0100 a48b c72d  .^H.6H.........-
000000f0: f90f 0100 488b 3648 8934 256d 0101 0048  ....H.6H.4%m...H
00000100: c7c0 6d01 0100 5048 c7c0 7a00 0100 5048  ..m...PH..z...PH
00000110: 89e0 4883 c008 4889 0425 7501 0100 48c7  ..H...H..%u...H.
00000120: c002 0000 0050 4d31 ff49 83c7 08e8 48ff  .....PM1.I....H.
00000130: ffff 4889 3c25 8501 0100 48c7 c03c 0000  ..H.<%....H..<..
00000140: 0048 c7c7 8501 0100 488b 3f0f 05         .H......H.?..

objdump -x /home/glaudiston/src/gelf/tests/test_s2i.elf

/home/glaudiston/src/gelf/tests/test_s2i.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64
/home/glaudiston/src/gelf/tests/test_s2i.elf
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000102:
EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000010078

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000010000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**0
         filesz 0x0000000000010000 memsz 0x0000000000010000 flags rwx

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols

I think I can try to set the memory using sys_mprotect call but I feel it is the wrong way... probably I am missing something on the program header... Still learning and I don't understand the alignment stuff.
Any tip on what to look for?

How did you create this ELF binary; with standard compiler tools, or by hand?  It specifies a segment of size 0x10000, 65536 bytes, to be mapped from the binary, but the file isn't actually that large.  Mappings are in 4KB page units, so even though your binary is less than 4KB, you get one full page mapped (padded with zero bytes), but pages after that are invalid.  This is the same as the behavior of mmap when you create a mapping larger than the backing file.

Why are you trying to access address 0x11000 anyway?  What do you think is going to be there?

Created by hand. I'm hacking to understand elf and linux memory mapping

I am coding a string copy with movsb and I expect to have the string there after the movsb unstruction. It works when using any address below 0100f8.

Right, because the first page goes up to address 0x11000; below that you have your code padded out by zero bytes; above that you have nothing.

I think what you want is to set the filesz of your segment to the actual size of the file 0x14d, not to 0x10000.  If you leave memsz at 0x10000, you'll get the first page of the segment mapped from your file, and the remaining pages allocated and filled with zeros, like a .bss section.  Then you can use that space for whatever you like.

So, any additional pages should be set using mmap? I seems strange since I already have it mapped on /proc/self/maps

No, you don't need to call mmap explicitly.  See my previous comment.

I don't know why, but if I set memsz to any other value than filesz it segfault; This is why I am setting both to 0x10000; I was trying to use memsz as a config to start the processes with some space to work with; I already have the remaining pages size until 4K to write... My try was to have more space there;

That is indeed what memsz is for, as I understand it, so I suspect your segfault is caused by some other bug.  Try asking a new question about that.

Yes, thanks; it fixed the issue; Please convert it to answer so I can accept it.
